# Create SOAP Attribute in JAXB

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, jax-ws

I am currently learning JAXB and Web Service and I have this problem that I dont know
how to solve.

Suppose I have this very simple class that I annotated with JAXB.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {
    private int custID;
    private String custName;
    //getters and setters
}
```

And I have this class that I am exposing as a Web Service. (Note:  I hardcode everything here for simplicity
but this connects to DB)

```
@WebService
public class CustomerWS {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "customerData")
    public Customer getCustomer(){
      Customer cust = new Customer();
      cust.setCustID(12345);
      cust.setCustName("John Doe");     
      return cust;
    }
}
```

The SOAP envelope response is like this.

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:customerDataResponse xmlns:ns2="http://test.com/">
         <return>
            <custID>12345</custID>
            <custName>John Doe</custName>
         </return>
      </ns2:customerDataResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Now suppose I have another property in the customer entity called status and they wanted this property as attribute to the soap
response to be like below instead of being part of the customer element. (A = Active, I = Inactive)

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:customerDataResponse status="A" xmlns:ns2="http://test.com/">
         <return>
            <custID>12345</custID>
            <custName>John Doe</custName>
         </return>
      </ns2:customerDataResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {
    private int custID;
    private String custName;

    //Another Annotation??? (A or I only)
    private String status;
    //getters and setters
}
```

How can I annotate my class to satisfy this requirement?  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything annotated on the Customer class will be relative to the customer element.

This is because JAX-WS is responsible for forming the message envelope, and then JAXB marshals the body of the message into this envelope.  When it comes time for JAXB to marshal the body it is too late to change the envelope.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Is there any alternative or workaround so that I could do what I want?  Also, is there a way that I could hardcode any attribute into the envelope even if its not part of any entity (Just plain hardcode any entity..)?